# C++ Tesseract OCR: Getting ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object still has count 1

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I installed **libtesseract-dev** (v4.1.1) on **Ubuntu 20.04** & I am trying out a **C++** code to **OCR** an image to searchable PDF.

My code is somewhat modified than the C++ API example code provided at [official website](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/APIExample.html):

*/home/test/Desktop/Example2/testexample2.cpp:*

```
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <tesseract/renderer.h>

int main()
{
    //const char* input_image = "/usr/src/tesseract-oc/testing/phototest.tif";
    //const char* output_base = "my_first_tesseract_pdf";
    //const char* datapath = "/Projects/OCR/tesseract/tessdata";
    
    const char* input_image = "001.jpg";
    const char* output_base = "001";
    const char* datapath = ".";

    int timeout_ms = 5000;
    const char* retry_config = nullptr;
    bool textonly = false;
    int jpg_quality = 92;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    if (api->Init(datapath, "eng")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
    tesseract::TessPDFRenderer *renderer = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(
              output_base, api->GetDatapath(), textonly, jpg_quality);
    */

    tesseract::TessPDFRenderer *renderer = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(
              output_base, api->GetDatapath(), textonly);

    bool succeed = api->ProcessPages(input_image, retry_config, timeout_ms, renderer);
    if (!succeed) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error during processing.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    api->End();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I also followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382664 as follows:

```
cd /home/test/Desktop/Example2

wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata

wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/tessdata/pdf.ttf

export TESSDATA_PREFIX=$(pwd)

gedit config
(In the config file, entered the contents:
tessedit_create_pdf     1       Write .pdf output file
tessedit_create txt     1       Write .txt output file
)

g++ testexample2.cpp -o testexample2 -ltesseract

./testexample2
```

But on execution, it displays the errors as follows:

```
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
Error during processing.
ObjectCache(0x7f1b096669c0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0x55af5c5241a0 still has count 1 (id /home/test/Desktop/Example2/eng.traineddatapunc-dawg)
ObjectCache(0x7f1b096669c0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0x55af5c506770 still has count 1 (id /home/test/Desktop/Example2/eng.traineddataword-dawg)
ObjectCache(0x7f1b096669c0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0x55af5c9a4a70 still has count 1 (id /home/test/Desktop/Example2/eng.traineddatanumber-dawg)
ObjectCache(0x7f1b096669c0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0x55af5c9a4980 still has count 1 (id /home/test/Desktop/Example2/eng.traineddatabigram-dawg)
ObjectCache(0x7f1b096669c0)::~ObjectCache(): WARNING! LEAK! object 0x55af5d7d5170 still has count 1 (id /home/test/Desktop/Example2/eng.traineddatafreq-dawg)
```

My directory structure is:

Example2
|------->001.jpg
|------->config
|------->eng.traineddata
|------->pdf.ttf
|------->testexample2
|------->testexample2.cpp

1. I have searched about this on multiple sources, but could not find any fix for this.
2. Further, I would like to know if there is someway I can build a binary using C++ compilation from this code + libtesseract such that my binary becomes a standalone portable binary, running which on other Ubuntu systems would not require reinstalling tesseract libraries & their dependencies

Answer (score -1):

You must free use dynamic memory for your class "api"

Use:

```
... you code...

if (renderer) delete renderer;
if (api) delete api;
```

Answer (score -2):

tesseract API examples is show case for using tesseract features without covering all  specifics of programming language of your choice (c++ in your case).

Just looking at your code even without trying it: you dynamically allocates memory 2x but you did not deallocate them. Try to fix these issues.

Comment: Ok, I would try to fix them. Also, please suggest about the possibility of point no. 2 (at the last)